Order months in Power BI filter by year/month
I have this filter in Power BI that's comprised of the calendar year and the month name. By default, it's showing the month names ordered alphabetically, how to order them by month number (i.e. first month is January).


Do you have a date column in your calendar table?

yes, I do have a date column

In that case, @Ryan below has posted the correct answer.

you can create another column which is monthn number and sort the month name column by month number
sort by other column
